# Unclear code in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I spent 4 hours trying to figure out what's going on in the following code. I can hardly understand it, since I haven't programmed Javascript yet.

Javascript:

```
function pincheck() {       
  var n = 123456789123,
  t = md5(n + " " + $("#wert").val()),
  e = $("input[name='some_hash']").val();
  $.post("https://url-test.com/site?check=" + t, {some_hash: e}, function(n) {
    $("#inputWert").html(n == t ? "<span style='color:green; font-weight:bold'>OK</span>" 
                                : "<span style='color:red; font-weight:bold'>NOT OK</span>")
  })
}
```

Corresponding HTML-form:

```
<form action="https://url-test.com/site" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <div style="display:none">
    <input type="hidden" name="some_hash" value="2cb6beab7ac4240043b20674a3dce6a5" />
  </div>    
  <input type="text" id="wert" name="wert" placeholder="WERT" onchange="pincheck()">
  <div id="inputWert">Please input</div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  <h2>Please explain<br/><textarea name="explain" style="width: 650px;height: 100px;" placeholder="Explanation"></textarea><br/>    
</form>
```

My thoughts were:

1. The function pincheck() checks if n==t
2. But since t is a md5 hash, it
       can never be equal to n, which is a digit number.
   Is this correct? If wert=000, will be the value of the variable "t" an MD5 of the string "123456789123 000"? I hope I explained correct.

The background of my question refers to our university IT-security task. We have to guess some number, and then enter it into the text form, whos id should be "wert" I guess.

I hope someone can help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have two `n`s in your code and one with number value set in the beginning is not the same as one returned in ajax callback - note `function(n)` signature.

Comment: yes, got it, thank you:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user types something into the `WERT` input field, the Javascript takes the user's input, puts `123456789123` at the beginning of it, calculates the MD5 hash of this, and assigns that to `t`. `e` is set to the contents of the hidden `some_hash` value.

Then it performs an AJAX query, sending `t` and `e` to the `url-test.com/site` script. `t` is sent in the `check` URL parameter, while `e` is sent in the `some_hash` POST data.

The server script returns back a string. If that string matches `t`, then it displays a green `OK`. If they don't match, it displays a red `NOT OK`.

My guess is this is part of a CAPTCHA test. The hidden input is a code that indicates which image was displayed. On the server, this code can then be used to look up the MD5 hash of the text in the image.

Comment: It's a pity that I can't vote up your answer. Thank you very much for it! I have another question: is there any chance to intercept that string returned by the server?

Comment: Open up Developer Tools, go to the Network tab, and you can view server responses.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to bruteforce the "wert", since its size was only 8 digits:)

Answer (score 0):

Simply, the Javascript is setting 3 variables (using the var keyword), then making an HTTPS POST call using jquery.

Picture the code like this line by line:

```
// Set n to a seemingly arbitrary number
var n = 123456789123;

// Set t to an MD5 hash using n and whatever the value of the "wert" element is
var t = md5(n + " " + $("#wert").val());

// Set e to the value of the element with a name of "some_hash"
var e = $("input[name='some_hash']").val();

// Makes a POST call to a URL built using the above variables
// Format $.post(URL, data(in JSON format), callback function)
$.post(
       "https://url-test.com/site?check=" + t, 
       {some_hash: e}, 
       function(n) {

           // Set the HTML body of the "wert" element
           // If n (returned by the POST call) is equal to t, set font color to green, otherwise set font color to red     
           $("#inputWert").html(n == t ? "<span style='color:green; font-weight:bold'>OK</span>" :
                                         "<span style='color:red; font-weight:bold'>NOT OK</span>")
       }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take your code in pieces: the "pincheck" function starts out by setting three variables: n (123456789123), t. which uses the javascript MD5 hash function with an initial string of n + some spaces + whatever value you enter into the "wert" field on your form. Finally, you retrieve the value of a hidden field called "some_hash" and store that in the variable "e"/ 
You then initiate a post to your server passing a key-value pair of "some_hash" (the key) and the value of the hidden field. 
When the post returns, it calls the anonymous function at the end of the post statement, passing in the returned value from the post operation as the (local to the anonymous function) variable "n". This "n" is a different variable from the one defined at the opening of the pincheck function. 
The anonymous function then checks to see if the value returned from the post operation is the same as the one calculated using the javascript MD5 function. If they are the same, then the first span tag is displayed, if they are not equal, then the second span tag is displayed. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: the main problem was that "n". Now I got it:)